# How To Change Text In Contempo Blogger Theme?

Tags: themes, blogger

I want to change the text of "Read More", "More Posts" and "Post a Comment" buttons in Blogger Contempo Theme.

Could someone please help me where to find the corresponding lines in the code?!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

1. To change "Read More" from your blog dashboard, go to **Layout** > **Blog Posts**, click edit (pen icon) and change **Post page link text**
2. To change "More Posts", go to your code and replace all `<data:messages.morePosts/>` with your text.
3. To change "Post a Comment", go to your code and replace all `<data:messages.postAComment/>` with your text.